# jackd server will not start exit code 225

Tags: sound, 13.04, alsa, jack

Could anybody explain the errors I am receiving using jackd with qjackctl

```
13:25:50.333 ALSA connection graph change.
13:26:11.822 JACK is starting...
13:26:11.822 /usr/bin/jackd -r -dalsa -dhw:2 -r44100 -p1024 -n3 -D -Phw:2
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
13:26:11.833 Could not start JACK. Sorry.
13:26:13.100 JACK was stopped with exit status=255.
```

I have used this before without issue but on 13.04 I cant get it to start at all using any of my audio devices, here is my current set up

[image: qjackctl setup]

Nothing is different from my 12.10 set up, I am a member of the audio group and hw:2 is the correct device, am I missing something ?

As a side note are there any alternatives to jack I could try ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel free to delete this question, but I will post my solution anyway. Do not install jack from the Ubuntu Software Center, instead use this command:

```
sudo apt-get install jackd qjackctl
```

I don't know why it works this way, but it does.

Comment: I’ve installed it from the terminal like you said karel but I still have that issue as well. oddly enough, i tried jack in windows and got it to work perfectly but in Ubuntu, it doesn't and I know that I can't set the options exactly the same as windows because things are different like the sound driver, etc. i've gotten it to work before but i don't know what I did. Any help will be great! Thanks!